heptapod: include version number in file name?
I'm trying to maintain an install script for Tryton ERP at Tryton community. I'd find it useful to have a version number in the file name; to manage this, when committing I'd like to have a prompt to enter the new version number.
Is such possible with heptapod (git), and can it be achieved without extensive programming knowledge (which I don't have)?
Greetings,
Wolf
